# Setting multiple value in select2 with select tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 api for multi-selection selectlists in my MVC C# project. I have binded the dropdown as following in code :

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlPackingParty", new SelectList(ViewBag.Parties, "ID", "Name"), new { @class = "select2 form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

and i have defined it with select2 in javascript as following code :

```
$(".select2").select2({
        placeholder: 'Select parties',
        multiple: true
    });
```

Everything worked until I tried to set it's value. I have searched the internet and most people have provided suggestion to set it like this `$('#ddlPackingParty').select2('val',["5","6","7"])` which is not working in my case. In my case it just sets the first value. It is not setting all 3 values.

I am running short of time. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting the tags option to true?

Comment: I have tried with tags option, but it is also not working :(